# Custom query for sidebar isn't returning results

Tags: wp-query, query, meta-value

I'm trying to create a shortcode that runs a custom query based on Yoast's primary category meta key.

The goal is to pull posts with the same meta key value of the post being displayed and show 4 more in the sidebar.

So far, everything is working but the query isn't getting posts with the same value.

I added an echo of the meta key value to make sure it was getting it, and it is.

Here's my code:

````
function primary_category_query_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts, 'primary_category_query' );

    $my_meta = get_post_meta ( $id, '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category', true);

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'posts_per_page'         => '4',
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category',
            'value'     => '$my_meta',
        ),
    ),
);

    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category', true);  

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>

    <section class="recent-posts clear">

    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ; ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'left' ); ?>>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>

    </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </section>

    <?php } else {
        echo 'Sorry, no more found.';
    }

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>```
````

Comment: So no error, it's just pulling incorrect posts?  In the DB, in post_meta, can you confirm that the `_yoast_wpseo_primary_category` is being assigned to posts?  Also, above this line `echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category', true);` can you add a `var_dump( $id );` and beneath that line `var_dump( $my_meta );` so we can verify what's there?  Want to make sure neither of those are empty.

Comment: adding the single quote marks turns this `'$my_meta'` into a string, you want to use the variable direct: `'value'     => $my_meta`

Comment: @TonyDjukic It's not pulling any posts currently. I pulled up the database and I'm confused by the results. [link](https://imgur.com/a/3rqgjUw) It seems like it's only being applied to 2 posts (if I'm reading right, I don't spend much time in databases), but I've assigned that meta to 6 posts and it's not showing the value I expected. Here's a picture of the output [link](https://imgur.com/VyUtv6F) since adding var_dump. "29" is the echo of the category ID I'm looking to pull from. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I'm new to queries obviously. And thank you!

Comment: @Michael Thank you! Still learning. :)

Comment: Good catch Michael, I completely missed that.

Comment: OK, it is echoing the correct category ID then. Can you try changing the $my_meta in the query args to just `$my_meta` without the quotes as Michael suggested.  Try that.  You may also want to go through those posts and make sure that it was assigned.  If it's empty in the database then it won't show up.  You can do a search in the database for `_yoast_wpseo_primary_category`.

IF it still doesn't work, try `(int)$my_meta` (that'll convert it to an integer) which is probably what the query is looking for.  Leave the `var_dumps()` in place and see if that changes the values.

Comment: @TonyDjukic I removed the single quotes and tested the others. The database still seemed off, so I installed the code on a different site. On the new site, I'm getting the same error, even with removing the quotes. The database is definitely showing the correct meta value on the new blog (category ID 72 in this case), with lots of posts in it. What I'm seeing now is: 
NULL bool(false) 72
Then 4 random posts (all unrelated and not even the most recent ones). 
I added (int), and it still shows me NULL... but removes the unrelated posts underneath.

Comment: Ok, if your first `var_dump( $id );` is giving `NULL bool(false)` then the problem is that we don't have a `post_id` to check against.  Which means everything after that isn't going to work.  Am I reading your screen caps correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our chat in the comments here's what I came with.  Please advise if it works.

```
<?php
function primary_category_query_shortcode( $post, $atts ) {
    //global $post;  //Uncomment this global if it still doesn't work.
    $atts = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts, 'primary_category_query' );
    $my_meta = get_post_meta ( $post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category', true );
    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array (
        'posts_per_page'         => '4',
        'meta_query'             => array(
            array(
                'key'       => '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category',
                'value'     => $my_meta
            ),
        ),
    );
    // All this would do is echo the ID of the category, correct?  Just for testing?
    //echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category', true);  
    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <section class="recent-posts clear">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ; ?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'left' ); ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </section>
    <?php } else {
        echo 'Sorry, no more found.';
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

An explanation, what I suspect may be happening is that your attempt to get the Yoast Primary Category isn't succeeding because, based on your var_dump() you're not getting the post ID, it's coming back as `NULL`.  So instead we'll include the $post in the `function()` and if that still doesn't work, we'll use `global $post;` to make sure it's being referenced. *(That would be the second line, just uncomment it if it doesn't work without it.)*

I've also commented out the `echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category', true );` because that would, in theory, just echo out the ID number of the category.  So I assumed you had that in there for testing.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. I tried it as-is and got the unrelated posts back, so uncommented global and it's working. (And yes, the post meta echo was just for testing.)

And thanks for the explanation too, very helpful as I'm learning all this!

Comment: You’re very welcome.  Sorry my reply was so delayed yesterday.  Welcome to the community.  

Comment: Mind if I ask a follow-up question? :D
This is working perfectly on my own site. But every other site I try to install it on gives me a warning: 
'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ... /wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 574'
Here are lines 571 to 580:
'function shortcode_atts( $pairs, $atts, $shortcode = '' ) {
 $atts = (array) $atts;
 $out  = array();
 foreach ( $pairs as $name => $default ) {
  if ( array_key_exists( $name, $atts ) ) {
   $out[ $name ] = $atts[ $name ];
  } else {
   $out[ $name ] = $default;
  }
 }'
Pulling my hair out. :)

Comment: Your foreach is `$pairs as $name => $default` but the code in my answer is `$defaults`. If when transferring the code over to other sites you shorted `$defaults` to `$default` that could be causing the problem.

Comment: Just checked that and it does have '$defaults' I just now copied and pasted the code exactly as it was from the working one to one of the sites it's giving me the warning on just to double check everything. I hoped it was a plugin conflict, but I disabled all other plugins and reverted to twenty nineteen, still got it. :/